# Should Chi Squared test for feature selection be applied on train dataset or the whole dataset?

Tags: feature-selection, machine-learning-model

I am working on building a logistic regression model. I am planning to run chi squared test for feature selection. Should I run it on train dataset or the whole dataset?

Comment: Always use only the training set for anything done before the model is trained. Always :)

Comment: Beware of statistical tests for repetitive tasks. Statistical test at 95% significance level allows every 20th test to be a fluke. How many features will you test? To answer you actual question, I agree with @Erwan

Comment: I have about 2000 features